libnvidia-glcore.so.1 causes segmentation faults
I have no idea why but for some reason no one, including root, can access /usr/local/lib/libnvidia-glcore.so.
I am using HardenedBSD 14.1-STABLE-HBSD. I am using Nvidia driver 390.154_1. My GPU is GeForce GTX 460. All my software for the moment comes from the package repositories, with the exception of OBS which is one of the programs that segfaults.
If you need additional information, please let me know.
The error (via gdb) always goes something along the lines of:
Invalid permissions for mapped object.
0x000000080608b220 in ?? () from /usr/local/lib/libnvidia-glcore.so.1

Standard user or root. Always a segfault. And when I look into it, it's always this particular library that's the problem.
I have searched through the list of sysctl settings in case something was enabled or disabled that might be causing this. Nothing jumped out at me:
hw.nvidia.gpus.0.type: PCIe
hw.nvidia.gpus.0.irq: 102
hw.nvidia.gpus.0.model: GeForce GTX 460
hw.nvidia.registry.dwords: 
hw.nvidia.registry.RmProfilingAdminOnly: 1
hw.nvidia.registry.EnableIBMNPURelaxedOrderingMode: 0
hw.nvidia.registry.EnableUserNUMAManagement: 1
hw.nvidia.registry.EnableBacklightHandler: 0
hw.nvidia.registry.EnableStreamMemOPs: 0
hw.nvidia.registry.UseThreadedInterrupts: 1
hw.nvidia.registry.TCEBypassMode: 0
hw.nvidia.registry.IgnoreMMIOCheck: 0
hw.nvidia.registry.VMallocHeapMaxSize: 0
hw.nvidia.registry.KMallocHeapMaxSize: 0
hw.nvidia.registry.MemoryPoolSize: 0
hw.nvidia.registry.EnablePCIeGen3: 0
hw.nvidia.registry.CheckPCIConfigSpace: 4294967295
hw.nvidia.registry.RegisterForACPIEvents: 1
hw.nvidia.registry.MapRegistersEarly: 0
hw.nvidia.registry.EnableMSI: 1
hw.nvidia.registry.UsePageAttributeTable: 4294967295
hw.nvidia.registry.InitializeSystemMemoryAllocations: 1
hw.nvidia.registry.UpdateMemoryTypes: 4294967295
hw.nvidia.registry.DeviceFileMode: 438
hw.nvidia.registry.DeviceFileGID: 0
hw.nvidia.registry.DeviceFileUID: 0
hw.nvidia.registry.ModifyDeviceFiles: 1
hw.nvidia.registry.RmLogonRC: 1
hw.nvidia.registry.ResmanDebugLevel: 4294967295
hw.nvidia.registry.Mobile: 4294967295
hw.nvidia.version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  390.154  Wed Jun 22 04:50:54 UTC 2022
hardening.kmalloc_zero: 0
hardening.prohibit_ptrace_capsicum: 2
hardening.prohibit_ptrace_syscall: 1
hardening.harden_shm: 2
hardening.harden_tty: 1
hardening.harden_rtld: 1
hardening.insecure_kmod: 0
hardening.procfs_harden: 1
hardening.log.ulog: 0
hardening.log.log: 1
hardening.version: 1400007
hardening.control.extattr.status: 1
hardening.control.acl.status: 1
hardening.pax.segvguard.max_crashes: 5
hardening.pax.segvguard.suspend_timeout: 600
hardening.pax.segvguard.expiry_timeout: 120
hardening.pax.segvguard.status: 2
hardening.pax.mprotect.status: 2
hardening.pax.pageexec.status: 1
hardening.pax.kmod_load_disable: 0
hardening.pax.tpe.user_owned: 0
hardening.pax.tpe.root_owned: 1
hardening.pax.tpe.all: 0
hardening.pax.tpe.negate: 0
hardening.pax.tpe.gid: 0
hardening.pax.tpe.status: 1
hardening.pax.disallow_map32bit.status: 2
hardening.pax.aslr.status: 1
hardening.pax.prohibit_new_usb: 0
security.mac.mmap_revocation_via_cow: 0
security.mac.mmap_revocation: 1
security.mac.labeled: 0
security.mac.max_slots: 4
security.mac.version: 5
security.bsd.stack_guard_page: 1
security.bsd.unprivileged_get_quota: 0
security.bsd.allow_read_dir: 0
security.bsd.hardlink_check_gid: 1
security.bsd.hardlink_check_uid: 1
security.bsd.unprivileged_chroot: 0
security.bsd.unprivileged_idprio: 0
security.bsd.allow_ptrace: 0
security.bsd.unprivileged_proc_debug: 0
security.bsd.conservative_signals: 1
security.bsd.see_jail_proc: 0
security.bsd.see_other_gids: 0
security.bsd.see_other_uids: 0
security.bsd.unprivileged_read_msgbuf: 0
security.bsd.unprivileged_mlock: 1
security.bsd.suser_enabled: 1
security.jail.mount_fdescfs_allowed: 0
security.jail.mount_zfs_allowed: 0
security.jail.mount_fusefs_allowed: 0
security.jail.mount_tmpfs_allowed: 0
security.jail.mount_procfs_allowed: 0
security.jail.mount_devfs_allowed: 0
security.jail.vmm_allowed: 0
security.jail.param.zfs.mount_snapshot: 0
security.jail.param.zfs.: 0
security.jail.param.sysvshm.: 0
security.jail.param.sysvsem.: 0
security.jail.param.sysvmsg.: 0
security.jail.param.allow.vmm: 0
security.jail.param.allow.mount.fdescfs: 0
security.jail.param.allow.mount.zfs: 0
security.jail.param.allow.mount.fusefs: 0
security.jail.param.allow.mount.tmpfs: 0
security.jail.param.allow.mount.procfs: 0
security.jail.param.allow.mount.devfs: 0
security.jail.param.allow.mount.: 0
security.jail.param.allow.nfsd: 0
security.jail.param.allow.suser: 0
security.jail.param.allow.extattr: 0
security.jail.param.allow.unprivileged_proc_debug: 0
security.jail.param.allow.read_msgbuf: 0
security.jail.param.allow.reserved_ports: 0
security.jail.param.allow.mlock: 0
security.jail.param.allow.socket_af: 0
security.jail.param.allow.quotas: 0
security.jail.param.allow.chflags: 0
security.jail.param.allow.raw_sockets: 0
security.jail.param.allow.sysvipc: 0
security.jail.param.allow.set_hostname: 0
security.jail.param.ip6.saddrsel: 0
security.jail.param.ip6.: 0
security.jail.param.ip4.saddrsel: 0
security.jail.param.ip4.: 0
security.jail.param.cpuset.id: 0
security.jail.param.host.hostid: 0
security.jail.param.host.hostuuid: 64
security.jail.param.host.domainname: 256
security.jail.param.host.hostname: 256
security.jail.param.host.: 0
security.jail.param.children.max: 0
security.jail.param.children.cur: 0
security.jail.param.dying: 0
security.jail.param.vnet: 0
security.jail.param.persist: 0
security.jail.param.devfs_ruleset: 0
security.jail.param.enforce_statfs: 0
security.jail.param.osrelease: 32
security.jail.param.osreldate: 0
security.jail.param.securelevel: 0
security.jail.param.path: 1024
security.jail.param.name: 256
security.jail.param.parent: 0
security.jail.param.jid: 0
security.jail.param.hardening.prohibit_ptrace_capsicum: 0
security.jail.param.hardening.harden_shm: 0
security.jail.param.hardening.harden_tty: 0
security.jail.param.hardening.harden_rtld: 0
security.jail.param.hardening.log.ulog: 0
security.jail.param.hardening.log.log: 0
security.jail.param.hardening.pax.segvguard.status: 0
security.jail.param.hardening.pax.mprotect.status: 0
security.jail.param.hardening.pax.pageexec.status: 0
security.jail.param.hardening.pax.disallow_map32bit.status: 0
security.jail.param.hardening.pax.aslr.status: 0
security.jail.devfs_ruleset: 0
security.jail.enforce_statfs: 2
security.jail.mlock_allowed: 0
security.jail.mount_allowed: 0
security.jail.chflags_allowed: 0
security.jail.allow_raw_sockets: 0
security.jail.sysvipc_allowed: 0
security.jail.socket_unixiproute_only: 1
security.jail.set_hostname_allowed: 1
security.jail.jail_max_af_ips: 255
security.jail.vnet: 0
security.jail.jailed: 0

Though I might have missed something.
List has been truncated for both time and security purposes. If there is an option you'd like me to look into that's not included here, let me know.
I've altered many sysctl variables and scoured the internet for hours. No one seems to be having my problem.
Reading through some old documentation, it seems that "/usr/lib/xorg" is supposed to exist. However on my system it does not. I am not sure if it's related, and XOrg seems to run fine, but I figure I should mention it just in case.

If I interpret this correctly, the error is not that libnvidia-glcore.so.1 is inaccessible. Instead, this is a stack frame, the code that is currently executing is in libnvidia-glcore.so.1, and this code is triggering the error.

This kind of low level debugging is rather new to me, so you'll have to forgive my ignorance; are you saying that libnvidia-glcore.so.1 isn't the issue?

The file itself or accessing it? No, not the issue. What’s inside, the code, running it? Apparently (part of) the issue. I’m not familiar with FreeBSD and running NVIDIA drivers on it, so I cannot offer further assistance, sorry.

That's okay. I would upvote your comment but apparently I can't. Thank you for the clarification.

@thehashslingingslasher I upvoted it, as it's a good comment. :)

I am currently seeking help on the Nvidia forums, but this appears to perhaps be an issue with the driver itself. I tried a 660 and am getting the same issue.

The fix turned out to be absurdly easy. Simply disable memory protection and page execution mitigations for the programs that fault.
hbsdcontrol pax disable pageexec /PATH/TO/PROG
hbsdcontrol pax disable mprotect /PATH/TO/PROG
